# Решение задачи со строками с помощью библиотеки sds.h в си

Tags: c, строки

Кто работал с библиотекой sds.h (документация https://github.com/antirez/sds) нужна помощь в решении задачи. Программа заменяет подстроки vk.com,  facebook.com,  [www.vk.com](http://www.vk.com),  [www.facebook.com](http://www.facebook.com) на ***(строго 3 звездочки),выводит измененную строку и количество изменений Нужно решить ее с использованием функций вышеуказанной библиотеки. Проблемы возникают с sdslen() не совсем понимаю как она работает,из-за этого возникают ошибки в работе memmove и memcpy.

```
#include "sds.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "string.h"

sds read_line(char adress[], int n);
sds antisn(char* adress);

int main() {
sds adress[400];
printf("Input adress: ");

read_line(adress, 400);
sds str_after = antisn(adress);

puts(adress);


}




sds read_line(char adress[], int n) {
int ch, i = 0;
while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n')
    if (i < n)
        adress[i++] = ch;

adress[i] = '\0';
return i;
}






sds antisn(char* adress) {
int i = 0;

sds wfb = "www.facebook.com";
sds vk = "vk.com";
sds fb = "facebook.com";
sds wvk = "www.vk.com";
sds zamena = "***";



for (;;) {
    char* p = strstr(adress, wfb);
    if (p != NULL) {
        memcpy(p, zamena, sdslen(zamena));
        memmove(p + sdslen(zamena), p + sdslen(wfb), sdslen(p + sdslen(wfb)) + 1);
        i++;
    }

    char* r = strstr(adress, wvk);
    if (r != NULL) {
        memcpy(r, zamena, strlen(zamena));
        memmove(r + strlen(zamena), r + strlen(wvk), strlen(r + strlen(wvk)) + 1);
        i++;
    }

    char* k = strstr(adress, vk);
    if (k != NULL) {
        memcpy(k, zamena, strlen(zamena));
        memmove(k + strlen(zamena), k + strlen(vk), strlen(k + strlen(vk)) + 1);
        i++;
    }

    char* q = strstr(adress, fb);
    if (q != NULL) {
        memcpy(q, zamena, strlen(zamena));
        memmove(q + strlen(zamena), q + strlen(fb), strlen(q + sdslen(fb)) + 1);
        i++;
    }
    if (p == NULL && q == NULL && k == NULL && r == NULL) return i;
}

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Нельзя вызывать `sdslen` из середины SDS-строки. Попробуйте так:

```
memcpy(p, zamena, sdslen(zamena));
memmove(
    p + sdslen(zamena),
    p + sdslen(wfb),
    sdslen(adress) - (p + sdslen(wfb) - adress)
);
sdsrange(adress, 0, sdslen(adress) - sdslen(wfb) + sdslen(zamena) - 1);
```

Comment: Переполнение в последнем аргументе sdsrange

Comment: Поправил, как мне кажется.